# Missing brace error on give command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, xbox-one

I’m typing in the command:

```
/give @p lever 64 0 {can_place_on : [“minecraft:iron_block”]}
```

and it keeps on coming up with:

> line 1 column 2 missing ‘}’ or object member name

I don’t see what I’m doing wrong

Comment: I'm not familiar with xbox commands, but I know that in 1.13 Java Edition the correct synax is /give @p lever{CanPlaceOn:["iron_block"]} 64. You could also try /give @p lever 64 0 {CanPlaceOn:["iron_block"]} If you're in 1.12 or under.

Comment: @SpiceWeasel the data tag is in the correct spot.  I think the issue is the spaces, which you aren't allowed to have within the data tag AFAIK.

Comment: I tried it without spaces but I didn’t work

Answer (score -1):

the spaces may be messing it up. try only doing `give @p lever 64 0 {CanPlaceOn:["iron_block"]}`.

Comment: The command didn’t work

Comment: okay. i'm not sure how accurate it is since i don't have my Xbox One near me at the moment to test, but the [Minecraft Bedrock Wikia page](https://minecraftbedrock.fandom.com/wiki/Thread:217291) says that ``/give @p <block> 1 0 {"minecraft:can_place_on":{"blocks":["<block>"]}}`` should work effectively.